# arules grouped matrix plot and labels in r

Tags: r, plot, arules

I'm currently using the `arulesViz` package in order to create some clusters within my rules.
You can have an exemple of the clustering method provided by the `arulesViz` packages.
The only thing which is bothering are the clusters labels which are not accessible throught the `attr(group_plot$mAggr, "dimnames")`.
looking at the `arulesViz` [code](https://github.com/cran/arulesViz/tree/master/R), I found that the labels are displayed through a `grid.text()` function.
Is there any way to have access to those labels since I cannot find any `gPath` argument to provide to the `grid.get()` function.

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
data("Groceries")

rules <- apriori(Groceries, 
                 parameter = list(supp = 0.01, conf = 0.1))

group_plot <- plot(rules,
                   method = "grouped",
                   measure = "support",
                   shading = "lift",
                   control = list(k=5,
                                  lhs_items =3))
```

Comment: Hi Pablo. What is it you'd like to do with the labels? Do you need to change the words of the labels or just their font / size / color? These require different approaches.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I need to extract the labels. I'm thinking about doing the clustering myself in order get the labels. Maybe I'll get the same result. I would lilke to reproduce the same output but with plotly.